# Removal of odd plumbing fixture

Tags: plumbing

[image]
All three fittings on this tee are the same.  The knurled thing for the left one has been moved up the line out of frame.  **I need to remove this line from the tee without damaging the tee or the other lines.**  I tried squeezing it with pliers and twisting while pulling on the other end, but no sign it moved.  I hope it’s not glued on.  Whether glued or not, I don’t see any reason for the knurled outer ring.

It’s in a 2003 RV, and it is probably original, i.e., eighteen years old.

Comment: Would try warming it a bit, location says a hair dryer.  Just want it a little bit warm.  Then try pulling and twisting off.

Comment: Worth a try.  And worth a regular answer, even if it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to preserve the plastic line (or can sacrifice an inch of its length), cut the line just downstream of the tee's nipple, creating a short cylinder of the hose material that's still stuck around the tee's nipple.

Then use an X-Acto or similar knife to cut the ring longitudinally — that is, parallel to the previous run of hose. Then you can pry under the edge of the ring where you just cut, and peel the cut ring off the nipple.

Comment: I probably don’t need to save it, but if it came to that, I could buy another.  I’ll try the hair dryer first.

Comment: @WGroleau I'd do the same. Remember that the age of the plastic line will have degraded its pliability. If you can remove the line with heat, be aware that if re-used, the line may seal to the nipple more poorly than it used to.

Comment: I ended up cutting it, leaving a little bit, to try to poke a barb nipple into it.  It's not flexible.  Winnebago ran the water pump output thru three elbows, two hose clamps, flexible tubing, three pieces of this rigid pex and five seemingly superfluous screw-on covers, wrapping all the way around the water pump to get to this connection four inches from the pump output.  And the one connection (of six) that was leaking was behind the pump, only reachable with a basin wrench (and that with difficulty).  Now it has two connections and a flex tube and all of it is visible from the outside.